# Reverse each iterable in a list using functional Python

Tags: python

I have a list of strings and lists. I want to reverse each iterable in my list using `map`. My current setup is as follows:

```
forwards_list = [
  'abc',
  'def',
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
]

def reverse(item):
  object_type = type(item)
  return object_type(reversed(item))

backwards_list = list(map(reverse, forwards_list))
print(backwards_list)
```

**Output:**

```
['<reversed object at 0x000000000A29A5C0>',
'<reversed object at 0x000000000A29A5C0>',
[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]]
```

**Desired Output:**

```
['cba', 'fed', [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]]
```

The problem seems to be that `list(reversed([]))` returns `[]`, whereas `str(reversed(''))` returns `'<reversed object at 0x000000000A335898>'`
. Can anybody help?

Comment: Not enough rep yet to comment, but try this location:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/931092/reverse-a-string-in-python

Comment: Mixing different kinds of things (strings & lists) within the same list is almost always a bad idea. It makes them universally difficult to work with and you probably started with them being separate in the first place.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're content to work only with sequences, you could use slicing rather than `reversed`:

```
def reverse(item):
    return item[::-1]
```

In general, sequences will return an object of the same time when slicing:

```
>>> 'foo'[::-1]
'oof'
>>> ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'][::-1]
['baz', 'bar', 'foo']
>>> ('foo', 'bar', 'baz')[::-1]
('baz', 'bar', 'foo')
```

There are a few types however where this certainly *won't* work (e.g. `dict`).  However, `reversed` requires sequences too (or objects that have a [`__reversed__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__reversed__) method).

```
>>> reversed(dict.fromkeys([1,2,3], None))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: argument to reversed() must be a sequence
```

You could handle this last case by type-checking and combining with your original solution:

```
import collections  # Need `collections.abc` on python3.4+ IIRC
def reverse(item):
    if isinstance(item, collections.Sequence):
        return item[::-1]
    obj_type = type(item)
    return obj_type(reversed(item))
```

Of course, even that won't work all (most?) the time since there is no rule (or even convention) to say that the constructor of an object must accept a reversed iterator generated from another instance of that type :0).